# What assertions should a response to a SAML Authentication Request include if the presenter and requested subject are different?

Tags: authentication, standards, saml, identity, saml-2.0

I'm evaluating a scenario using the SAML v2 Authentication Request Protocol (3.4) where the *presenter* and *requested subject* are different, i.e. where the presenter is authenticating to the identity provider in order to get assertions about another subject.

My question is: What assertions are required in response to such a request, and about which subjects?

---

Under this scenario, the `<AuthnRequest>` identifies a subject using a `<saml:Subject>` element. A `<Response>` to an authentication request contains assertions. From the start of section 3.4, "Such assertions MAY contain additional statements of any type, but at least one assertion MUST contain at least one authentication statement."

Under "3.4.1.4 Processing Rules", I identify the following rules for a successful response:

- The responder MUST ultimately reply to an `<AuthnRequest>` with a `<Response>` message containing one or more assertions that meet the specifications defined by the request (line 2229)
- If the `<saml:Subject>` element in the request is present, then the resulting assertions' `<saml:Subject>` MUST strongly match the request `<saml:Subject>`, as described in Section 3.3.4
- All of the content defined specifically within `<AuthnRequest>` is optional, although some may be required by certain profiles. In the absence of any specific content at all, the following behavior is implied:

  - The assertion(s) returned MUST contain a `<saml:Subject>` element that represents the presenter.

It seems to me like these rules require the `<saml:Subject>` in each response assertion to be equal to both the requested subject and the presenter.

I'm using the "Assertions and Protocols for the OASIS Security 
Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0" ([saml-core-2.0-os](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf)) as my reference.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "[i]n the absence of any specific content at all" is critical to understanding the standard here. Since including a `<saml:Subject>` in the request means that the request *does have* specific content, the final bullet point in my question does not apply.

However, the first part of section 3.4 still says:

> Such assertions MAY contain additional statements of any type, but at least one assertion MUST contain at least one authentication statement.

The subject of these assertions must then be the requested subject, as per the processing rules.

The required authentication statement must refer to this subject (who was arguably never authenticated). If this corresponds to a `<AuthnStatement>` element, that element requires:

- The `AuthnInstant` attribute for when the authentication took place
- A `<saml:AuthnContext>` describing the authentication context. This may then be left to `<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>`